# Scala Parser, set reserved words

Tags: parsing, scala

I am writing a simple proggramming language with scala parser. So far no trouble, but im worrying about the relation *function name* / *variable name* against *reserved words*.

I'va already addded some special functions like `"floor" ~ gexp` or `"top" ~ gexp` and i dont want anybody using this language being able to name a function or a variable like them. I have not found yet a way to check this.

in Ruby i would write something like

```
rule varname
    lowerid &{ |id| id[0].is_not_reserved } <VarNameNode>
```

but i dont know how would i write this in scala

```
def varName : Parser[StringValue] = lowerid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `^?` operator:

```
def varName: Parser[StringValue] = lowerid ^? ({
  case id if !isReserved(id) => id
}, { id => s"Error: $id is reserved." })
```